# IE 11 renders resized images without antialaising

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, resize, antialiasing

I have a page whereby images on the server are scaled down with CSS (a 300x600px image would be scaled to 100x200px by the CSS for example)

In Chrome and Firefox, these images are displayed correctly, with appropriate anti-aliasing.
The problem lies with IE 11, which shows the images completely without anti-aliasing, making them look jagged and sharp.

Due to the particular requirements of the project, the image re-sizing must be done through CSS.

I have tried adding `-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;`, but this does not work as it has been depreciated for 'modern' versions of Internet Explorer.

Is there any way to make IE render these re-sized images with anti-aliasing? 
In my opinion, this should be something IE does automatically, as every other browser on the market seems to have no problem handling re-sized images.

Comment: Can you post a reproduction link in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image interpolation in IE10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595014/image-interpolation-in-ie10)